# Not getting 240 volts out of stove plug getting 120 out of each side but not 240 when testing live

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image][image]I just brought a mobile home. The electric stove was not working so I tested it. At the plug I got 120 when testing each live with neutral but when I test the 2 live I got nothing.

Brought a new 50 amp dual for it and getting the same. Moved 50 amp up 1 space in case it was on the same bus but still got the same results. Next I pulled the main just to make sure of the bus and tested 50amp with and without wires hooked up.

The service into mobile is 100amps and it's a Cutler Hammer box.

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE
NOW PLUGGED INTO 50 AMP AT THE SERVICE PANEL OUTSIDE AND STILL NO 240 VOLTS ONLY GETTING 120 FROM EACH OF THE LIVE WIRES ON BREAKER AND 120 FROM LIVE AND NEUTRAL

Comment: Please upload a picture of the breaker panel. That sounds like you either have a double "half size" breaker installed wrong, or your incoming power is only 120V with the two incoming hot wires connected together.

Comment: Picture is added

Comment: Did you test voltage across the two main feeder wires to verify you actually have 240 v coming in?

Comment: Across the 2 wires going into main breaker did not think that was safe to do

Comment: CAREFULLY test across the main feeds, be sure you have 240 coming in, Do you have any other 240 volt circuits you could test (like a dryer or water heater) for 240?

Comment: That's weird not getting nothing on multimeter when crossing the 2 main and no other 240 to test

Comment: See the RV stand panel there?  Unplug the 30A plug on the far left. What happens if you do?  Now, stick your voltmeter probes in the 4-prong socket just to its right.  Do you get voltages? Don't measure from the one on the top, that's just ground and is not a player.

Comment: That's the only plug going into the house

Comment: Update found out the mobile home is plugged into 30 amp out getting a 50 amp extender then going to try the stove and circuit breaker after plugging into 50 amp

Comment: You can't just "get an extender". The other end *which we can't see* connected to the panel has to be done right *and* **all** wire involved has to be big enough to handle 50A.

Comment: Well plugged into 50 amp at service panel still only getting 120 from each live no 240 at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on (a) your range double (not tandem) breaker showing 0V hot-hot **and** (b) your main breaker showing 0V hot-hot, your problem is at the utility connection. There are two possibilities:

- Utility is only supplying 120V

In this case, you are stuck unless you can get a utility upgrade. Which means your total power is 100A @ 120V, **not** 100A @ 240V. You'll need to replace your 240V appliances (which appears to be just the range) with 120V appliances.

- Utility is supplying 240V but only connected one hot to your mobile home

My hunch is that this should only happen if at the outside connection (service feed) only one of your hots was present and so they connected one hot and neutral and ground but did not connect the second hot *plus* somewhere (maybe outside, maybe inside your panel) the two hots for your panel were jumpered together (there are good and bad ways to do that).

If it is the second case, you need a qualified electrician to do the fix. The fix should be easy but because this is *before* your main breaker, it is very dangerous if you don't know exactly how to do it right.

#### Update Based on RV Plugin

It looks like you are plugged in to the 30A 120V connection on an RV subpanel. By definition, that will only give you 120V, and only 30A total. You should be on the 50A 240V connection. You need to replace the existing plug/cable. Doing so *correctly and safely* may be trivial or may be a bit complicated. The good news is that once you unplug it is safe to work (no power at all). Pictures showing where the other end of that cord attaches to your mobile home would help.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the mobile home is set up in a rv park on a rv lot don't know if that matters pics of rv hook up will be on top

Comment: Ask the RV park manager if the supply is expected to be 240V.  Ask them if you can try a different site.   Or .... sorry to say it ... you could try a different park.  Vines, cocoons and wasp nests all inside the service connection box says "neglect" to me.  The answer to your question might just be "nobody cares".

Comment: The plug goes underground so iam guessing that the wires end up inside my panel

Comment: @jay613 My understanding from many previous questions on DIY SE is that a standard RV subpanel as 50A @ 240, 30A @ 120, 20A @ 120. That matches the breakers in the picture. And the *not in use* receptacles match the 50A @ 240 and 20A @ 120, meaning the plug is in the 30A @ 120. So 240V is available, but it is currently plugged in to 120V. Whether changing that requires only a new plug and cord or requires reconfiguring the panel, we just don't know.

Comment: The cable plugged in to the service panel then goes underground?  Can you see its other end?  Is it plugged into an inlet on the side of the home or wired straight into the panel?

Comment: And what's with the screw on the main breaker inside?  I've never seen anything like that before ... is it normal?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the panel has a 100A main and 40A for the range so hopefully THAT isn't the problem.  The festering service panel and the power cord running underground don't hold a lot of promise though.

Comment: Iam figuring the problem is Iam only plug into the 30amp plug iam looking for a 60amp to amp extender locally

Comment: @jay613 That is to hold the breaker. **REQUIRED** when you have a backfed breaker as the main instead of a special main breaker (top or bottom in a special position separate from all the others).

Comment: Plugged into 50amp service and still no 240 volts only getting 120 from each live

Comment: **HOW** did you plug it in? Did you just chop off a connector and splice on another one? Or did you actually deal with the internal panel connections to the external cable? Depending on how things were done, this could (if not done deliberately and carefully) resulted in anything from "120 only" (which you got) to "all kinds of stuff zapped with huge flash" (fortunately that didn't happen). But while conceptually this is simple, it needs to be done *right* in order to be *safe*.